# Tag suggestions are empty

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design

**<strike>It apears to have been resolved by now. 
The issue still appears on SO</strike>
 The issue regressed here on MSE as well**

I recently got access to the 10K-tools, and the inline tag editor, which I observed to crop the suggested tags by the boundaries of the tag box on my mobile, using the responsive design.

While writing this question on a desktop, I noticed the same problem on the ask a question page. See attached screenshot, where there should be a suggested design tag, but it is hidden.

When I use the inline tag editor on the question using FF on a desktop, it works as expected.

Regular editor:
[image]

10K inline tag editor:

[image]

Using FF 68.5.0esr on Mac and using Chrome 85.0.4183.81 on Android.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate on MSO: [Tags tooltip not working](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400873/4642212).

Comment: Got nothing to do with inline editor or mobile device: it's empty everywhere and anywhere. JS code bug, that is also not browser specific.

Comment: Same here. An annoying regression.

Comment: @Drew the prod deploy is happening right now

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask pedantic maybe, but the JS is innocent here; the problem was at the server

Comment: @Marc well, the server did send a result back so couldn't know the result isn't proper. :)

Comment: @Marc by the way, any chance the fix broke notifications? [Didn't get notification for your comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6Qqa.png)... :-( (oh ooops wrong circle, but you still see the comment directed at me below)

Comment: @user400654 not now.. this one worked.

Comment: @Shadow well I got the notification, so...

Comment: @Marc me too, now. Just random glitch then? Notification going poof?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is my fault, a side-effect of some infrastucture changes. Sorry. Working on getting a fix out ASAP.

For those who are interested in code things: some newly "async" code was not properly "awaited", and the result (now a future/promise, not a value) was handed to a JSON serializer, which duly serialized... the future/promise :(

For those who are *not* interested in code things: it is now fixed.

Answer (score 13):

It's not being "cropped".  There are literally no child elements in the `.tag-suggestions` div.

[image]

Even though the data is being returned.

[image]

Comment: Adapted the title based on your research.

Comment: The second image here should be sufficient for anyone suitably experienced in .NET to be able to chuckle in a way that says "heh, I know what Marc did there..."